# AzureDevops : howto maintain sprint order in query?

Tags: azure-devops

When drag-dropping items in Boards | Sprints one can change the order. We use this while discussing with the team and use that order as 'what should be done first'.

In a query selecting items from the current sprint, that order is not preserved and there seems no field to filter on to get the items in the same order as in the sprint.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to your requirements, you could try to use the “`Backlog priority`(Scrum) or `stack rank`(Agile, CMMI, Basic)” field to order the work item in query.

Here are the steps:

Step1 : Select the **“Tree of work items”** query and set the Filter options :**”Parent/Child”**

[image: Query Settings]

Step2: Add the column **“Backlog priority“** or **”stack rank ”**.  You could set the column as **ascending order**.

[image: Column]

Then the sorting in query will be similar to that in sprint.

Here is a doc about [“Backlog priority “or ”stack rank ”](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/backlogs-overview?view=azure-devops#backlog-priority-or-stack-rank-order).